# Disable Validation for Prisma file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, prisma

VS Code official Prisma extension validates files without defining datasource as an error, is there a way to disable that behavior

**Error**
[image: error]

**No Error**
[image: no error]

The ideal solution would be to just enter disable rule as you do in typescript ex: // @ts-ignore

Answer (score 0):

Update `"prisma.validateWithoutDatasource": false` in `settings.json`